# Installing a library (WiiRemoteJ) into NetBeans

Tags: netbeans, java

I downloaded the WiiRemoteJ java library from here:

http://dl.qj.net/wii/homebrew/wiiremotej-v14.html

But I don't know how to install it into netbeans to use with a project!

I went to tools>Libraries, then clicked New Library... then typed "wiiremotej" as the name. Under class path, I navigated to the "WiiRemoteJ.jar" file. Then I added the JavaDocs folder.
When I created a new project and tried to import the library, (import WiiRemoteJ.*;) it gives me an error and says "Package WiiRemoteJ does not exist"!

The same thing happened with another wii remote library I tried (motej)

Does anyone know what i am doing wrong?

Comment: This also does not work with Box 2d.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the most straight forward approach would be to right click the project's *Libraries* node, and select **Add JAR/Folder**. This way you can use the JAR right away, without any additional registration.